# extracting xml node(not text but complete xml ) and with other test nodes from xml file using SAX parser in java

Tags: java, xml, sax, stax

I have to read from large xml files each ranging ~500MB. The batch processes typically 500 such files in each run. I have to extract text nodes from it and **at the same time extract xml nodes from it**. I used xpath DOM in java for easy of use but that doesn't work due to memory issues as i have limited resources.

I intent to use SAX or stax in java now - the text nodes can be easily extracted but i don't know how to extract xml nodes from xml using sax.

a sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Library>
  <Book name = "ABC">
    <Author>John</Author>
    <PrintingCompanyDT><Printer>Sam</Printer><Printmachine>Laser</Printmachine>    
    <AssocPrint>Oreilly</AssocPrint> </PrintingCompanyDT>
  </Book>
  <Book name = "123">
    <Author>Mason</Author>
    <PrintingCompanyDTv<Printervkelly</Printer><Printmachine>DOTPrint</Printmachine>
    <AssocPrint>Oxford</AssocPrint> </PrintingCompanyDT>
  </Book>
</Library>
```

The expected result:
1)Book: ABC:
Author:John

PrintCompany Detail XML:

```
<PrintingCompanyDT>
  <Printer>Sam</Printer>
  <Printmachine>Laser</Printmachine>
  <AssocPrint>Oreilly</AssocPrint> 
</PrintingCompanyDT>
```

2) Book: 123
Author : Mason
PrintCompany Detail XML:

```
<PrintingCompanyDT>
  <Printer>kelly</Printer>
  <Printmachine>DOTPrint</Printmachine>
  <AssocPrint>Oxford</AssocPrint>
</PrintingCompanyDT>
```

If i try in the regular way of appending characters in public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) method
I get the below 
1)Book: ABC:
Author:John
PrintCompany Detail XML :

```
Sam 
  Laser
      Oreilly
```

exactly the content and spaces.

Can somebody suggest how to extract an xml node as it is from a xml file through SAX or StaX parser in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be tempted to use [XOM](http://xom.nu) for this sort of task rather than SAX or StAX directly.  XOM is a tree-based representation similar to DOM or JDOM but it has support for processing XML "twigs" in a kind of semi-streaming fashion, ideal for your kind of case where you have many similar elements that can be processed independently of one another.  Also every `Node` has a `toXML` method that prints the node as XML.

```
import nu.xom.*;

public class LibraryProcessor extends NodeFactory {
  private Nodes empty = new Nodes();
  private bookNum = 0;

  /** Called for each closing tag in the XML */
  public Nodes finishMakingElement(Element element) {
    if("Book".equals(element.getLocalName())) {
      bookNum++;
      // process the complete Book element ...
      processBook(element);
      // ... and throw it away
      return empty;
    } else {
      // process other elements (except Book) in the normal way
      return super.finishMakingElement(element);
    }
  }

  private void processBook(Element book) {
    System.out.println(bookNum + ": " +
        book.getAttributeValue("name"));
    System.out.println("Author: " +
        book.getFirstChildElement("Author").getValue());
    System.out.println("PrintCompany Detail XML: " +
        book.getFirstChildElement("PrintingCompanyDT").toXML());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Builder builder = new Builder(new LibraryProcessor());
    builder.build(new File(args[0]));
  }
}
```

This will work its way through the XML document, calling `processBook` once for each `Book` element in turn.  Within `processBook` you have access to the whole `Book` XML tree as XOM nodes, but without having to load the entire file into memory in one go - the best of both worlds.  The "Factories, Filters, Subclassing, and Streaming" section of the [XOM tutorial](http://xom.nu/tutorial.xhtml) has more detail on this technique.

This example just shows the most basic bits of the XOM API, but it also provides powerful XPath support if you need to do more complex processing.  For example, you can directly access the `PrintMachine` element within `processBook` using

```
Element machine = (Element)book.query("PrintingCompanyDT/PrintMachine").get(0);
```

or if the structure is not so regular, for example if `PrintingCompanyDT` is sometimes a direct child of `Book` and sometimes deeper (e.g. a grandchild) then you can use a query like

```
Element printingCompanyDT = (Element)book.query(".//PrintingCompanyDT").get(0);
```

(`//` being the XPath notation for finding descendants at any level, as opposed to `/` which looks only for direct children).

Comment: Hi, Ian. Thanks for your reply . Your program works for me. As an extractor, the memory part also works fine. I have to add persistence logic to submit to db and do a memory test.

Comment: One question i have is assuming i have multiple <library> in my file and i am processing separate catching events for Book and PrintCompanyDT. Note - consider PrintCompanyDT is not the direct child of Book, it is grand child of book.....when i try to process- the result seems to be--first the printCompanyDT  gets printed and then the book author  is printed - for every book tag. Is the behavior because we are targeting the closing tag....can we do the reverse of it?

Comment: I think you'd be better off sticking to doing all your processing within `processBook` - you have the whole XML tree of the `Book` element and XOM has nice XPath support that allows you to easily extract grandchildren, etc.  I've edited my answer with some more details.

Comment: Thanks Ian ...Xpath support makes it easy for me. I will give it a try by EOD and let u know.

Comment: Ian, i implemented as suggested as a single extract and used xpath for getting children/grand/grand grand....and some complex string operations. The program works pretty fast. I didnt get a chance to do the persistence part as i have to do a lot more complex operations before going to that step. But i guess it will work as the current speed is  pretty fast compared to what it was prior ....thanks a lot for your help.